# inline-block vertical centering issue

Tags: html, css

I have the following simple code snippet. It is taken out from my application where .a1 is a container button, which has an icon. The icon should be vertically middle aligned to the parents line-height/height, but it is shifted with 1px from top. Could you explain me why this is the behavior? Is there any solution?

```css
.a1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #f00;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="a1"><i class="i"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why?**

Because inline-block elements render with "white-space". You can see this in this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/cg0xbgce/)** where no height/width is set on the parent element.

When you use `vertical-align:middle;` the "white space" is rendered before the element (on top) (black line in the demo). This space moves the child element down and therefore it doesn't appear verticaly centered.

**how to fix :**

You can use `display:block;` and calculate the margin to apply to the child element so it centers verticaly and horzontaly.

You can also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) which talks about white space and ways to avoid them.

Comment: As Roland Soós pointed out in his own answer, setting font-size 0 on the parent will work exactly because of this. The white space will have no size. But I wouldn't like to count on it so using margin is correct.(or flexboxing)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems like font-size:0; for .a1 seems also a fix for such issue.

```css
.a1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 0;
}
.i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #f00;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="a1"><i class="i"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.a1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #000;
}
.i {
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 6px 6px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="a1"><i class="i"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, this is a possible fix for the issue, but do you have any explanation what cause the original issue? My code seems logic for me, but it doesn't behave like yours. If I could get an explanation, that could help me with future problems with vertical align middle. Thanks!

Comment: Using line-height with vertical-align makes sense for fonts.  However, it doesn't play nice with block elements.  Although the line-height was 28px, the font-size inside the block was inheriting from the parent container.  My theory is it was trying to vertical-align based on the size of the font inside the container....even though there are no fonts in the container.

Comment: You gave me an idea to test it with font-size: 0; on the parent element and it seems like that can also fix this problem.

Comment: Cool.  Glad I could have some input.

Answer (score 0):

```
.a1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #000;
}
.i {
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 6px 6px;
  background-color: #f00
```